# Error (little-endian) reading a XLS file with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, encoding

I download a XLS file from the web using selenium.

I tried many options I found in stack-overflow and other websites to read the XLS file :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('test.xls') # Read XLS file
Expected "little-endian" marker, found b'\xff\xfe'
```

And

```
df = pd.ExcelFile('test.xls').parse('Sheet1') # Read XLSX file
Expected "little-endian" marker, found b'\xff\xfe'
```

And again

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
book = open_workbook('test.xls') 
CompDocError: Expected "little-endian" marker, found b'\xff\xfe'
```

I have tried different encoding: utf-8, ANSII, utf_16_be, utf16
I have even tried to get the encoding of the file from notepad or other applications.

Type of file : Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet (.xls)
I can open the file with Excel without any issue.
What's frustrating is that if I open the file with excel and just press save I then can read the file with of the previous python command.

I would be really grateful if someone could provide me other ideas I could try. I need to open this file with a python script only.

Thanks,
Max

**Solution**(Somewhat messy but simple) that could potentially work for any type of Excel file :

Called VBA from python to Open and save the file in Excel. Excel "clean-up" the file and then Python is able to read it with any read Excel type function

Solution inspired by @Serge Ballesta and @John Y comments.

```
## Open a file in Excel and save it to correct the encoding error 
import win32com.client
import pandas

downloadpath="c:\\firefox_downloads\\"
filename="myfile.xls"

xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Application.DisplayAlerts = False # disables Excel pop up message (for saving the file)
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=downloadpath+filename)
wb.SaveAs(downloadpath+filename)
wb.Close
xl.Application.DisplayAlerts = True  # enables Excel pop up message for saving the file

df = pandas.ExcelFile(downloadpath+filename).parse('Sheet1') # Read XLSX file
```

Thank you all!

Comment: The file that you downloaded is probably not in XLS format, nor in UTF-8 CSV formats. But there are still tons of possible format and without knowing more about that file I really cannot guess...

Comment: I can open the file with Excel with no problem. 
It has a .xls extension when I download it. Type of file : Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet (.xls) 
The website I download the file from access a MySQL database to generate this excel file. i think the source code they used to do this is C#
It has about 10 columns for 80 rows.
I could try to send a sample

Comment: Excel can detect and load many formats. Have you a message about changing format when you open the original file and then save it back?

Comment: There isnt any message when I Save or Save As or Save As a .xlsx file. It just saves it and then I can open it using pandas.read_excel for example

Comment: As I have already said, without an example of the file (not its content), I cannot guess the format...

Comment: For future reference, code snippets can be formatted with four spaces at the start of the line. This will ensure that it's given a monospace font and visually distinguishes your code from the rest of your question.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Since I can not upload the Excel file. Maybe you could tell me what you would do if you had it?

Comment: @BHustus I corrected the formatting of my post accordingly thanks

Comment: Unix and Linux have a `file` command that helps to know what is the format of a file, on Windows, right click and *properties* in explorer can help. An hex editor can also be useful...

Comment: What @SergeBallesta is trying to get at is that the file extension doesn't really mean much. And once Excel has opened the file, when it saves it again, it will have potentially used a different format than what it opened, *even if it uses the same extension*. (When this happens, it is usually because the original extension was not an accurate reflection of what the **real** file format was.)

Comment: Another very common occurrence is that an Excel file generated by third-party software (other than Excel) is written incorrectly. It is very easy to get wrong. However, Excel is pretty robust and often accepts "somewhat incorrect" files. If Excel is confident that it has coped properly with the problems, it may not report encountering any errors. And as mentioned before, once it is open in Excel, saving it again will write it as a clean, problem-free file.

Comment: Thanks @JohnY and @SergeBallesta! I worked something out called Excel with Python. It is a little messy but at least it works.

Answer (score 1):

I got away from this one by using the following:

```py
# Read content in bytes from whatever is your source, then:
content = content[:28]+b'\xFE\xFF'+content[30:]
with open('file.xls', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(content)

# This works now
df = pd.read_excel('file4.xls')
```

Based on this:
https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/master/xlrd/compdoc.py#L90

Answer (score -2):

What does **pd** mean?? What

**pandas** is made for data science. In my opinion, you have to use **openpyxl** (read and write only xlsx) or **xlwt/xlrd** (read xls...  and write only xls).

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
book = open_workbook(<math file>)
sheet =....
```

It has several examples with this on Internet...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this already thought:           from xlrd import open_workbook
     book = open_workbook('test.xls')

    CompDocError: Expected "little-endian" marker, found b'\xff\xfe'

Comment: CompDocError means your file is corrupted or something like this.  Maybe first check if the file get to open correctly on excel.  Otherwise, paste this file here, I am going to try on m'y side...